# How to change language of angular leaflet-map?

Tags: angular, google-maps, dictionary, internationalization, leaflet

Is it possible to change the language of leaflet map tiles? Like changing the names of country and states to the preferred language like German/french/Chinese which ever user chooses.Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this plugin is for you : https://github.com/buche/leaflet-languageselector

`EDIT :`

The problem is that you're using tiles which are only png files. You can see in your `network console` the files loading when you zoom. It look like this :

[image: Leaflet tile]

[image]

It's not pure HTML/CSS so you can't have access to the name of countries and change it to the desired language.

You would need to render your own tiles or find another tile provider here : http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/ (which is not really great ...)

You can also try mapbox because they are using vector : https://www.mapbox.com/help/change-language/

https://www.mapbox.com/help/change-language/#change-label-language-in-mapbox-studio-classic

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Baptiste .leaflet-language selector is only a language selector to choose a language. It wont apply the language through out in map.Can u please suggest a way to apply the language change on click of language selector provided by this plugin.